# internet access

Tags: wireless, internet

I am new to to Ubuntu. My laptop is connected to the WiFi but I am not being able to access internet. However the same WiFi is working on my mobile. If any other information is reqd than I can provide the same.

Comment: What is the output of `lspci | grep Network`?

Comment: Should I type this in the terminal?

Comment: 02:00.0 network controller: broadcom corporation bcm4313 802.11bgn wireless network adapter (rev 01)

Comment: Did you install drivers for your card?

Comment: How so I do it?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: I checked to install drivers. In my case it says that no need to install anything. The driver I have is [14e4:4727] (rev 01).

Comment: Did you check out the DNS answer below? Do you remember ever installing the drivers?

Comment: when i ping Google's DNS server, i am getting the msg "From 192.168.0.106 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable"

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely having a DNS problem.  You can check if you have intenet connectivity by pinging a host that may certainaly be connected.  Try pinging Google's DNS server:

```
$ ping -c10 8.8.8.8
```

If you get a positive response try add an entry to the top of your /etc/resolv.conf file:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 8.8.8.8
search [your preferred domain suffix such as mydomain.com]
```

The search option isn't a requirement, but can be a convenience facility to use single word host names for your local machines.

If your internet browsing starts working after the resolv.conf change, you can make this automatic by adding a head to your resolvconf configuration files:
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN


nameserver 8.8.8.8
search [mydomain.com]
```